# Push notifications work for development, not production

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I have been trying for the past how long to figure out how to go from the sandbox APNS to production APNS. Below is the PHP code used to send notifications to my app.

```
$passphrase = 'SomethingStrong';

$ctx = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/ck.pem');
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);

$fp = stream_socket_client(
    'ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
    $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);

if (!$fp)
{
    //return json_encode(array('response' => 'connection_fail'));
}

$body['aps'] = array(
    'alert' => $message,
    'sound' => 'default'
    );

$payload    = json_encode($body);
$msg        = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;

$result     = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));

if (!$result)
    return json_encode(array('response' => 'unsuccessful'));
else
    return json_encode(array('response' => 'successful'));

fclose($fp);
```

This whole thing works when I keep the URL `ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195`, but when I when I change it to `ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195` no notifications come through my app, yet PHP outputs that it was sent successfully.

I'm code-signing with the development certificates.

I'm new to notifications and have never used them before, so sorry if I'm doing something really obvious. Thanks.

Comment: You need to set production.pem file for sending production notification.

Comment: @Alec Check [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1) for certificate generate.

Comment: @PramodTapaniya I re-did the certificate process and it still didn't do anything.

Comment: @Yash I used his tutorial, re-did the certificates, and nothing.

Comment: @Alec for getting production notification on the iPhone, You must install app on iPhone via adHoc provision profile.

Answer (score 1):

There are two things, you need to confirm:

- You generate your build with distribution provisioning profile
- You use production pem file for sending PUSH from your PHP server

[image: Push Notification Certificate]

Comment: I can't build with the distribution profile and run it on my phone. How do I do that? I can only run the development profile.

Comment: You should be able to do that. When you will run with your app from Xcode with your distribution profile, it would get installed but won't run the first time. Open your app again from home screen, and you have distribution build installed.

Or you can simply create a ipa file with distribution profile, and install it in your device.


or if you are facing some other error, please do tell.

Comment: I keep getting this... "The entitlements specified in your application’s Code Signing Entitlements file do not match those specified in your provisioning profile. (0xE8008016)."

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22625785/entitlements-file-do-not-match-those-specified-in-your-provisioning-profile-0xe

Comment: None of that is working. I did all the certificate stuff right, but when I build for distribution I can't put it on my phone. I can put the developer code-signing on the phone, but I still need sandbox in the PHP code.

Comment: Should I release the distribution code-signed app to the App Store and see if it works or not when it's live?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105215/discussion-between-gunjot-singh-and-alec).

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the correct ssl socket `ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195` for production.

Check the certificates or the `ck.pem` file you have upload to server should be production.

Also check for the **provisioning profile** which you select for build should be **Distribution profile**.

Comment: I can't build with the distribution profile and run it on my phone. How do I do that? I can only run the development profile.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25056144/xcode-6-how-to-pick-signing-certificate-provisioning-profile-for-ad-hoc-distri

Answer (score 0):

Everything was setup correctly, but I had an issue with my Ad Hoc profile and the way it was code-signing. All is good now! Thanks!