# The executable was signed with invalid entitlements 0xe8008016 - Distribution certificate

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile, code-signing-entitlements

I am getting error:

```
The executable was signed with invalid entitlements.
The entitlements specified in your application’s Code Signing Entitlements file do not match those specified in your provisioning profile. (0xE8008016).
```

on `DISTRIBUTION CERTIFICATE & PROVISIONING` Profile. Earlier, I was able to install the build using distribution profile, But, now I am not able to do so. It gives above error.

Below is my entielement contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">

<plist version="1.0">

<dict>

<key>keychain-access-groups</key>

<array>

<string>$(AppIdentifierPrefix)com.myapp.xyz</string>

</array>

</dict>

</plist>
```

I have enabled `PushNotification` in my appid.

From past 2-3 days, I have gone through many such post on stackoverflow and tried various solutions. But none of them has worked.
Things I have done to resolve,

1. Created a new cert and provisionf profiles
2. Removed old certs from keychains and installed new ones
3. Removed old provision profiles from system and installed new ones (Manully and automatically through `Xcode->Preferences->account->view Details-> download all`)
4. `Restareted XCode` many times after removing certs adding new ones
5. Clean and build project
6. Cleared derived data
7. Kept Provisioning profile on automatic (but it builds with developer provisioning profile, dont know why)

According to error, I have matched my provision profile Application services (as per my appID in developer portal) with build capabilites in `XCode`. But its not working. 
Does that `.entitlements` file has to do anything with "Build capabilites"? I tried removing `.entitlement`once but no luck.

UPDATE:
I created a new project, New appID (The default ones are enabled. In-app and game center) and new distribution provisioning profile. Still gives same error. :(

UPADTE 2: Adding image of keychain[image]

Comment: Can you look this. It may help you. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2415/_index.html

Comment: Thanks Ramesh_T. Looking intot that.

Comment: Did your issue resolved with provided link?

Comment: No, I just created new appID (Just for testing. Only game center and In-App purcahse enabled by default) & new Distribution provisioning profile using my new appID. Used that appId & provisiong profile In project. Removed old entitlements file and path in build Settings.Restarted system too. But Stil same error. I m not sure but could it be a certificate issue?

Comment: Did you check that the WWDR cert is the new one?

Comment: Yes Matt, its new one.

Comment: Can you show your entitlements for your project? Also, in your post it wasn't clear - Are you unable to install and run on a device? Are you unable to debug?  Simply stating that it is not working is not sufficient. We would need to know what exactly is not working.  Your sentence "arlier it used to work so I know it just installs the app & dosent allow to debug." isn't a clear statement. Consider rephrasing to make it more clear.

Comment: @wottle I am not able to install and run on a device. I have also added entitlements file. I also tried by making a simple Hello World project and used new appid and new provisioning profile. but that too didnt work. See my update for that.

Comment: @JiteshW I think this is issue which every iOS developer encountered at least once. I will suggest to avoid anything automatic. Set all Prov. Profiles and team manually. I have struggled a lot from automatic settings of Xcode. In order to help you wee need all your settings... team, signing identity, prov. profiles.... I would recommend to start from scratch again

Comment: @IAmDav, I had started from scratch except creating a new distribution certificate, But, Couldnt solve. Should I revoke tht too?

Comment: @JiteshW I'm not sure is distribution certificate revoking will solve your problem. But I'm sure problem comes from automatic settings.

Comment: @IAmDav I have done both things. Used automatic as well and simply keeping only 1 provisiong profile in system and using that.

Comment: JiteshW, actually the reason can be differ of this error, do u have a look on following answers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240801/the-entitlements-specified-profile-0xe8008016-error-ios-4-2

Comment: @IAmDav, Tried but no result :(

Comment: @JiteshW , do you added new capabilities by mistake? check this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22625785/entitlements-file-do-not-match-those-specified-in-your-provisioning-profile-0xe?rq=1

Comment: @IAmDav, No I have not added new capabilites. Also I tried most of the combination with capabilities, that too didnt work. See my Update in question, In which, I created a new project, new app id, new provisioning profile. That too didnt worked.

Comment: @JiteshW, Could you print screen your keychain public and private keys?  and certificate, are they valid??

Comment: Do you have the Apple Push Notification certificate?
And try to set the certificate and provision profile yourself - just to check that it's not a problem with the "automatic" choosing the wrong one

Comment: @Roee84, Yes I do have apple push notif certificate and I tried both option for setting provisiong profile.

Comment: @IAmDav, I have added keychain access image

Comment: @JiteshW click on each certificate, on header part of keychain app you will see "This certificate is valid" if everything is ok. Are certificates which you use valid? if not I will suggest delete all, and create from scratch

Comment: Did you set the Push notifications at the capabilities?

Comment: @IAmDav, All keychain certificates are valid :)

Comment: @Roee84, Yes, I have set push notificaion at the capabilities. Infact I tried both.

Comment: Check the capabilities tab in xcode maybe their is an error there

Comment: Hi @JiteshW, did you resolve this issue? Just like you, I have tried everything but still couldn't get it to work. An update is greatly appreciated! Thanks!!!

Comment: @SeaJelly, Actually I moved to some other project. But couldn't solve that issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The entitlements specified...profile. (0xE8008016). Error iOS 4.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240801/the-entitlements-specified-profile-0xe8008016-error-ios-4-2)

Answer (score 98):

Look into the test target, the team should be the same in both the test target and the main target.

[image: test target team]

[image: Error 0xe8008016 - Distribution certficate]

Comment: Awesome, unlike many other posts, this answer actually solved my problem. I was using different teams. Using the same on both targets fixed it. Thanks a lot, Mici!

Comment: I searched for 3 hours to find a solution to my problem, and this was it. Oh my goodness.

Comment: I was using manual singing in the main target and the test target was using automatic. After **setting both target to automatic with the same team**, it worked again, thanks. 

Comment: I feel like there needs to be a way that this answer pops up as a recommended site as soon as you start typing entitlements iOS in your browser search bar!

Comment: What is a Test target and what is a Main target? This answer is poorly explained.

Answer (score 3):

Issue is due to distribution provisioning profile try using development or Ad-Hoc provisioning,Hope it's work ,Good luck

Comment: Yes, development provisioning is wokring fine. But, I want build with distribution provisioning profile

Answer (score 0):

In my case, before the build I have added a key `ITSAppUsesNonExemptEncryption` in `Info.plist` which may not included in the provisioning profile. After removing `ITSAppUsesNonExemptEncryption` from `Info.plist` I am able to build successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue, and it was due to the existing builds in TestFlight expiring, so it's worth checking the build you've installed hasn't expired before doing any further investigation.