# iOS Firebase push notifications not appearing

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, apple-push-notifications, entitlements

I've set up push notifications according to this walkthrough: https://www.appcoda.com/firebase-push-notifications/

But when I send a test message from Firebase, it doesn't show up. I followed all the steps, I have valid certificates:

[image]

Provisioning Profile set up for push notifications:

[image]

Under my App ID it shows that notifications are enabled:

[image]

And I have the certificate uploaded to Firebase:

[image]

And in my `AppDelegate` `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`:

```
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
        let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
            options: authOptions,
            completionHandler: {_, _ in })
        // For iOS 10 data message (sent via FCM
        FIRMessaging.messaging().remoteMessageDelegate = self
    } else {
        let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
            UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
    }


    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
```

Along with the Firebase callback method in `AppDelegate`:

```
func applicationReceivedRemoteMessage(_ remoteMessage: FIRMessagingRemoteMessage) {
    print(remoteMessage.appData)
}
```

And obviously I have imported:

```
import UserNotifications
import FirebaseInstanceID
import FirebaseMessaging
```

I'm not sure why the push notifications are not working, it seems like everything is in place. The only thing out of the ordinary I did was remove the entitlements from Target -> Code Signing, as it was giving me an invalid entitlements error when I tried to run the app. Now that it's removed, the app is running fine. I do have an open question about that separate issue but for now I'll assume that's not the cause of my problems here.

And just to confirm, I don't have to re-download the Google plist after adding notifications? I was using Firebase in my project before adding notifications, so I already have one.

Thanks for any help getting the notifications working!

Comment: please remove the device from Xcode and try ur getting the push or not?. and some times in development mode did register with notification not calling.

Comment: Do any of you know if it's required to re-download the Google-Info.plist file after adding FirebaseMessaging/notifications? I had Firebase in my app before I tried to add notifications so I have the original plist.

Answer (score 1):

Try Adding `FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled type "Boolean" value "NO" in your info.plist`

and maybe add `Messaging.messaging().shouldEstablishDirectChannel to true in your AppDelegate`

Answer (score 0):

Can you check in the capabilities tab if push notifications are enabled. Also, since Xcode 8 you need to add the entitlements file with aps-environment set. If you disable and enable the push notifications from capabilities you will get this file.

Comment: Please have a look at the documentation - https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/EntitlementKeyReference/Chapters/EnablingLocalAndPushNotifications.html

Comment: Your "Also, since Xcode 8 you need to add the entitlements file with aps-environment set." is misleading. That happens automatically if you set in the capabilities.

Comment: Push notifications are enabled in capabilities. I switched it to "off", then back on again. Re-downloaded my provisioning profile, double clicked to install. Ran and now I'm getting an error "invalid entitlements"

Comment: @Honey Prior to Xcode 8 entitlements file was not required.

Comment: It seems to be working now, but I'm still not seeing the test notifications I'm sending out from Firebase

Comment: @KingTim Can you check in you target's build settings.
Code Signing Entitlements has correct file name.

Comment: @KingTim for the invalid entitlements see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19581225/the-executable-gets-signed-with-invalid-entitlements-in-xcode). And just to be sure. Are you using the simulator or an actual device? Because your simulator isn't able to create a token for you. Only actual devices can do that for you

Comment: @Honey I'm using my device

Comment: @JasveerSingh the correct entitlements file name is there. It's giving me the invalid entitlements error again.

Comment: Just FYI, when your app is in foreground you will not see any default notifications. So send the notification while app is in background mode or killed.

Comment: @KingTim did you see the link I shared for invalid entitlements? Try to first solve that issue on that page. Once it's fixed come back here and try solving the issue of not receiving any notifications.

Comment: @Honey, I looked and tried every solution there. I also have an open question about the same issue. I've toggled and untangled all the recommended capabilities, regenerated provisioning profiles, cleaned, restarted Xcode. No luck.

Comment: @KingTim Then you should have not opened this question! Try to comment on the answers of your question and fix that issue first. I mean how do you expect it to work while you still have that issue?! You can place a bounty on it, but you can do it after 48hrs

Comment: To be clear, the app runs if I simple delete the entitlements from Target -> Code Signing. Is removing the entitlements like that causing this issue with the push notifications not working?

Comment: Don't remove the entitlements, try to fix the issue with entitlement. Push notifications will not work without it.

Comment: I've tried every suggestion on every question on the topic I can find. If you know how to solve the entitlements issue, please don't be shy! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44412788/invalid-entitlements-error-when-adding-push-notifications