# Cannot get entitlements error to go away

Tags: ios, xcode

No matter what, I am not able to get the entitlements error to go away:

> The executable was signed with invalid entitlements.
>
> The entitlements specified in your application’s Code Signing Entitlements file are invalid, not permitted, or do not match those specified in your provisioning profile. (0xE8008016).

I don't use anything, no game center or in-app purchases, but by default this is checked on developer.apple.com and I cannot uncheck it.

Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KYKeY.jpg

My capabilities section in xcode looks like this:

Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJRLJ.png

I even created an entitlements file and added "game center" to it, but i cant figure out how to add "in app purchases" to it:

Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/h2jAT.png

Does anyone have any ideas?

I have been trying and building for hours now, since 5am in morning, its now 3:15pm, I'm going nuts, I tried everything in these topics:

- [The executable gets signed with invalid entitlements in Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19581225/1828637)
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/26847090/1828637

I opened my dist.mobileprovision file in TextEdit and it shows this, I removed sensitive info i think.

```
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>AppIDName</key>
    <string>REMOVER REMOVED</string>
    <key>ApplicationIdentifierPrefix</key>
    <array>
    <string>REMOVER REMOVED</string>
    </array>
    <key>CreationDate</key>
    <date>2018-05-04T15:35:06Z</date>
    <key>Platform</key>
    <array>
        <string>iOS</string>
    </array>
    <key>IsXcodeManaged</key>
    <false/>
    <key>DeveloperCertificates</key>
    <array>
        <data>REMOVER REMOVED</data>
    </array>
    <key>Entitlements</key>
    <dict>
        <key>keychain-access-groups</key>
        <array>
            <string>REMOVER REMOVED.*</string>      
        </array>
        <key>get-task-allow</key>
        <false/>
        <key>application-identifier</key>
        <string>REMOVER REMOVEDorg.reactjs.native.trustedscore2</string>
        <key>com.apple.developer.team-identifier</key>
        <string>REMOVER REMOVED</string>
        <key>beta-reports-active</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
    <key>ExpirationDate</key>
    <date>2018-06-10T00:39:11Z</date>
    <key>Name</key>
    <string>REMOVER REMOVED</string>
    <key>TeamIdentifier</key>
    <array>
        <string>REMOVER REMOVED</string>
    </array>
    <key>TeamName</key>
    <string>Noitidart Saab</string>
    <key>TimeToLive</key>
    <integer>36</integer>
    <key>UUID</key>
    <string>REMOVER REMOVED</string>
    <key>Version</key>
    <integer>1</integer>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I even copied and pasted the section from the entitlements here to my entitlements file and it still gave me this error.