# Xcode 6 Trying to Sign iOS 8 App like an OS X App

Tags: ios, xcode, ios8, xcode6, provisioning

*Xcode 6.0, iOS 8.0*

I've been happily signing and shipping betas of my app all week. Suddenly today, I am getting this error in Xcode's Organizer when I try to Export the app for ad hoc distribution:

> Failed to locate or generate matching signing assets ... No matching provisioning profiles found for "Applications/ PilotPro.app"

[image: Failed to locate or generate matching signing assets ... No matching provisioning profiles found for "Applications/ PilotPro.app]

With a path like `Applications/*.app` it seems like Xcode is trying to sign it like a Mac app or something.

I have re-downloaded provisioning profiles until my fingers bleed, and I get no errors during building, just this one during export in Organizer.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out this solved my problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10356589/1142348

I deleted the entitlements in my app and added them again and the problem was solved.