# iOS8 - failed install project including widget extention on under version of os device

Tags: ios7, widget, ios8

I have tried to install iphone project including widget extention on OS7 device... but it's failed.
If I install on OS8 device, it's fine.

Error message shows

The executable was signed with invalid entitlements.

The entitlements specified in your application’s Code Signing Entitlements file do not match those specified in your provisioning profile. (0xE8008016).

Do you have any advice? Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240801/the-entitlements-specified-profile-0xe8008016-error-ios-4-2

Comment: thank you for link.. but it's not duplicated because I can install on OS8 device.

Comment: It is not about version of ios. Your devices that matters. Different devices have different IDs. Make sure your device is added in your provision profile you are using.