# The executable was signed with invalid entitlements (0xE8008016) - tried all other solutions

Tags: ios, xcode

I know this has been asked a hundred thousand times, but after 3 hours none of the answers have provided any solution to my issue.

I recently changed an app I'm developing from ad-hoc distribution to enterprise distribution. I also updated to Xcode 7.1 this morning (although I'm not sure if it's related). With nothing else changing in my application, whenever I try to compile the application now and install it on my device, I get the error that the Code Signing Entitlements file toes not match the entitlements in the provisioning profile.

[image: Xcode error]

My entitlements:

`$ cat GoDriver/GoDriver.entitlements`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>aps-environment</key>
    <string>development</string>
    <key>keychain-access-groups</key>
    <array>
        <string>$(AppIdentifierPrefix)com.rudylimo.GoDriver</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

The App ID on the developer portal:

[image: Apple Developer Portal]

And my apps capabilities:

[image: App Capabilities]

I've attempted to run the app on 2 devices and a simulator and it will only run on the simulator.

**EDIT:**

After some more testing, if I remove the `aps-environment` row from my entitlements file, the app builds and installs properly (but without push notifications working).

Comment: You don't say what you did in terms of switching over to new provisioning profiles etc. Have you gone through all the solutions here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240801/the-entitlements-specified-profile-0xe8008016-error-ios-4-2

Comment: I've walked through all steps in the linked question. To change provisioning profiles, I generated the new one for Enterprise Distribution on Apple's portal, resynced all my provisioning profiles through Xcode's preferences, changed it in my app target.  After that, I uninstalled the app from my phone, cleaned the project and tried to run the app through Xcode.

Comment: Have you found any solution to this issue? I am facing the same problem