# Error 0xE8008016

Tags: iphone, ios, code-signing

I ran into another iPhone problem again.  I finished my app, and I need to test it on my phone before I submit it to the app store.  But, whenever I press Run, I get an error message like this.

"The entitlements specified in your application’s Code Signing Entitlements file do not match those specified in your provisioning profile.

(0xE8008016)"

I have a Provisioning profile for development and distribution, and certificate with keys for develoment and distribution as wells as my device is listed in the portal.

I'm not really an expert at Xcode, so if you do answer, can you please explain a fix detailing every step.  I know lots of other people have asked this problem, but I can't follow there answers.

Thanks in advance,
Will

Comment: Read [question 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240801/the-entitlements-specified-profile-0xe8008016-error-ios-4-2) and [question 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410080/code-sign-error-with-xcode-3-2) on stackoverflow.
And before asking Do search.

Answer (score 0):

Having the provisioning profile isn't the same as setting it in your build settings to run with the project.  Click your Target on the left sidebar and then click the Project.  Click the Build Settings tab.  Under code signing, select the proper provisioning profile in each of the drop down boxes.  It should build properly after that, assuming you do have the proper provisioning profile and certificate.

If you're just now testing on your phone right before you submit to the store that's a whole other problem, but I suppose you'll figure that out yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Check that the build configuration you use is not pointing to some Entitlements.plist file, which in its turn might be non-existent or containing wrong data about certificate/profile pair. If that the case, the settings in latter will override anything you set in the build settings resulting in having wrong actual certificate used.

To double-check this find your configuration in the "Code Signing Entitlements" section in the Target/Project Build Settings.

In my case I had exactly the same alert when it was pointing to an "entitlements.plist", which could not be found anywhere in the project. Clearing any mentioning of this file for the target build configuration fixed the problem for me.