# How CarPlay Entitlement Works In Enterprise Apps?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, entitlements, carplay

I am developing CarPlay addition on our app. Which is distributed with the **Enterprise In distribution method, so we do not have a product in the App Store**. I am wondering if **CarPlay support can be provided in applications distributed with the Enterprise in distribution method?**
If this is not possible, I will inform management that this is not possible. I am waiting for your answers, thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11971137/does-ios-enterprise-program-allow-to-add-entitlements-to-provisioning-profiles E enterprise apps cannot have special entitlements. Now may be a good time to investigate moving from enterprise apps to custom apps

Comment: What source are you basing this information on? If you have a document you can share, I would appreciate it. I couldn't find much documentation on this subject.

Comment: I don't believe that it is documented; why not try to fill in this form https://developer.apple.com/contact/carplay - it will be rejected if your program does not qualify